# Enterprise Distribution not playing nice with iOS8 in Swift App

Tags: ios, xcode5, ios8, code-signing

I'm having issues running Enterprise builds onto iOS 8 devices with my swift app. It seems to be working fine if i use a non-enterprise account to code-sign. Is anyone experiencing this issue?

Here is a crash log that I am getting on an iOS device when attempting to run a build with an enterprise account to codesign:

> OS Version:          iOS 8.0 (12A4345d) Report Version:      105
>
> Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP) Exception Codes:
>   0x0000000000000001, 0x00000001200d5088 Triggered by Thread:  0
>
> OS Version:          iOS 8.0 (12A4345d) Report Version:      105
>
> Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP) Exception Codes:
>   0x0000000000000001, 0x00000001200d5088 Triggered by Thread:  0
>
> Dyld Error Message:   Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib
>   Referenced from:
>   /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/EFD559CA-9D7C-481D-9CA5-BF0B8EB6A3F5/Beta.app/Beta
>   Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
>   /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/EFD559CA-9D7C-481D-9CA5-BF0B8EB6A3F5/Riva
>   Beta.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib: mmap() error 1 at
>   address=0x100478000, size=0x00194000 segment=__TEXT in Segment::map()
>   mapping
>   /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/EFD559CA-9D7C-481D-9CA5-BF0B8EB6A3F5/Beta.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib
>   Dyld Version: 353.5
>
> Binary Images: 0x1200d4000 - 0x1200fbfff dyld arm64 
>    /usr/lib/dyld 0x182b58000 -
>   0x182b58fff Accelerate arm64  
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate 0x18436c000
>   - 0x1844cefff CoreGraphics arm64  <60c80ae53baf35cabcb3e09d2a454b55> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
>   0x184b08000 - 0x184b78fff CoreTelephony arm64 
>   <2e0d3b51a01330e7a8a08a05a25dfa12>
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
>   0x184f70000 - 0x1851c4fff Foundation arm64 
>   <473783d2bf1a3ceb969a4a863831eba4>
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation 0x185344000
>   - 0x1855defff ImageIO arm64   /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO 0x186a5c000 -
>   0x186b2ffff MessageUI arm64  <3ddc5ee0fd4e36a3bee79ed61ec5d705>
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/MessageUI.framework/MessageUI 0x186ba4000 -
>   0x186c53fff MobileCoreServices arm64 
>   
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
>   0x1880b4000 - 0x188238fff QuartzCore arm64 
>   
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore 0x1884cc000
>   - 0x18851dfff Security arm64  <8436c45c606d3d28b2938904dbf0b206> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security 0x1886e4000 -
>   0x188757fff SystemConfiguration arm64 
>   
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
>   0x18875c000 - 0x1890b8fff UIKit arm64 
>   <3989dfad77f33a8ea10e009f0dba82a3>
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit 0x194488000 -
>   0x194559fff libsqlite3.dylib arm64  
>   /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib

Comment: @vburojevic no, but i just read up about a solution people are using that i am going to try. you basically revoke all certificates/related provisioning profiles and regenerate them

Comment: I've tried regenerating distribution profile only, no luck.
Let me know how was your result please.

Comment: @vburojevic i don't think it works by just regenerating the distribution profile only. you have to revoke all certificates and provisioning profiles, then regenerate them

Comment: Hey guys, facing the same issue. Did anyone get the solution on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All explained in details in this article :

https://www.airsignapp.com/ios-apps-using-swift-crash-when-signed-with-inhouse-certificate/

> We can confirm that after create a new cert and
> .mobileprovision, no more issues.
>
> We found origins that caused this issue, related to a missing attribute in
> “Subject” field InHouse Certificates :
>
> BEFORE Subject: UID=269J2W3P2L,
> CN=iPhone Distribution: Company Name, O=Company Name, C=FR
>
> AFTER Subject: UID=269J2W3P2L, CN=iPhone Distribution: Company Name,
> **OU=269J2W3P2L**, O=Company Name, C=FR

Comment: If anyone is wondering how to view the Subject of a cert: `openssl x509 -in ~/Desktop/dist.cer -inform DER -text -noout | grep Subject:`

Answer (score 2):

I think Apple has already summarized it under [Swift app crashes when trying to reference Swift library libswiftCore.dylib](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1886/_index.html)

Refer to my previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26024100/dyld-library-not-loaded-rpath-libswiftcore-dylib/31672991#31672991).

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change Swift Compiler - Optimization level setting to "None" in Build settings of the target. It should help.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this myself and tried a whole host of solutions but nothing worked. The only thing left to try was to revoke both the certificate and provision and to re-generate both. This ultimately resolved it for me.

Comment: I didn't have to revoke the old cert, but had to remove the old provisioning profile from "Keychain Access" to force code signing to use the updated cert.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue without creating a new certificate.

1. upgrade system to MacOSX 10.10
2. upgrade Xcode or command line tools to 6.1
3. Install Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certificate to keychain. (Download from this page http://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/ and the direct download url is http://developer.apple.com/certificationauthority/AppleWWDRCA.cer )